# Unable to import pyspark to python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have pyspark script(p1) which have dataframes created and returns dataframe. the same is being imported into different python script(p2). when i run p1 directly script executes successfully however when i run p2 it failes saying "no module found p1". I have import p1 into p2 script.

Please advise.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Pass the python script using `--py-files` argument

- If you are using pyspark repl  add the conf py-files and pass the path to your file.
- if you're submitting the job using spark-submit then add --py-files argument

Comment: Could you advise?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i was not clear on what i have been doing in the above message.

```
p1:

import... 
spark = SparkSession.() 
def func(query) 
    df = spark.sql(query) 
    return df

p2:
import...
import p1
df2 = p1.func('select * from tab')
df2.show()
```

Then running p2 as python3 p2.py -- it says Module p1 not found

When i run p1 itself it works

I removed spark related commands and put few python functions such as print('abcd') it works fine. So i am missing something to import related to pyspark.